# How to calculate sensor_msgs/Imu data from IMU sensor

Tags: imu, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a Shimmer2R module from which I obtain 9 axis: Acceleration X, Y, and Z; Gyroscope X, Y, and Z; and Magnetometer X, Y, and Z.

I would like to transmit this data using standard ROS messages. I found the
[sensor_msgs/MagneticField](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/MagneticField.html) messages for the magnetometer. I thought the [sensor_msgs/Imu](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html) messages would be appropriate for the other data.

However, the Imu message seems to present the data in a different way than how I obtain it. I am unfamiliar with this representation and I'm looking for guidance on how to convert my data to the `sensor_msgs/Imu` representation. An internet search didn't provide me with any useful pointers.

On a side note, I have also read that to obtain a heading from the magnetometer, the data from the Gyroscope is also necessary. Is there any ROS node that does this calculation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96006/how-to-calculate-sensor_msgs/imu-data-from-imu-sensor/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shivesh_sk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18061/shivesh_sk/) on 2014-06-24**:
Hi, I also want to interface Shimmer2R module in ROS groovy running on Ubuntu. But I don't know how to interface Shimmer2R module on linux. Any help would be more than appreciated.

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-06-24**:
I've quickly thrown what I have on GitHub: https://github.com/RafBerkvens/shimmer. It supports a shimmer Bluetooth connection, but documentation is lacking and there a lot of work in progress. But you might find inspiration in the Python script accel_gyro_mag.py.

**Comment by [shivesh_sk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18061/shivesh_sk/) on 2014-06-24**:
Thanks a ton! I will check it out. :)

## **Comment by [shivesh_sk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18061/shivesh_sk/) on 2014-06-25**:
I tried your executing your node but I am getting this error:
================================================================================REQUIRED process [shimmer/accel_gyro_mag-1] has died!
process has died [pid 3166, exit code 1, cmd /home/shivesh/catkin_ws/src/shimmer-master/scripts/accel_gyro_mag.py __name:=accel_gyro_mag __log:=/home/shivesh/.ros/log/7e16bdb6-fc6a-11e3-9f41-001e65ca05f4/shimmer-accel_gyro_mag-1.log].
log file: /home/shivesh/.ros/log/7e16bdb6-fc6a-11e3-9f41-001e65ca05f4/shimmer-accel_gyro_mag-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!

Shimmer2R modules are working normally on my linux. I am able to get the data in a CSV file through ShimmerConnect application for linux. Also, I didn't understand how your program will identify the shimmer we want to connect. For eg, I don't know where to put its rfcomm id for communication.

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-06-25**:
Bluetooth settings are configured on lines 101 and 102. Admittedly, the code is undocumented. I believe that issues with this specific node are better handled on the GitHub website than using these comments.

**Comment by [shivesh_sk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18061/shivesh_sk/) on 2014-06-25**:
Hi I updated my bd_addr and port as directed. But still it throws an error. I have put the issue in the github. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IMU data does map pretty well to your data:
angular_velocity would be your gyro data and linear_acceleration the acceleration data.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-30**:
Seems fair enough. Any idea what I could do with the orientation quaternion?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-14**:
Depends on how far you want to go. The simplest is to just integrate the gyros. The better solution is to include the accells and filter all data.

**Comment by [kerollosghobrial](https://answers.ros.org/users/24333/kerollosghobrial/) on 2016-04-28**:
but how can i integrate with the other sensors. do you can a code to give me the orientation Yaw, pitch and roll ?thanks in advance